# Непонятное выражение ++x+-+y+-+z++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int x,y,z;
auto& cout = (std::cout << ++x+-+y+-+z++);
int main(){}
```

Как работает этот код и почему выводит `1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну давайте разбирать...

```
#include <iostream>
int x,y,z;
```

Раз эти переменные объявлены в глобальной области видимости, они обнулены.

```
auto& cout = (std::cout << ++x+-+y+-+z++);
```

Переменная `cout` в глобальном пространстве имен оказывается ссылкой, возвращаемой выражением

```
std::cout << ++x+-+y+-+z++
```

которое возвращает ссылку на `std::cout`, но при этом выводит... Итак, что же оно выводит?

```
++x      // - x становится равным 1, и возвращает 1.

+ - +y   // - т.е. прибавить минус от плюс `y`

+y == 0
-(+y) == 0
```

так что прибавляется 0

```
+-+z++
```

То же самое, только `z++` при вычислении устанавливает `z` равной 1, но возвращает 0. Так что опять - просто прибавить 0.

Итак, выражение выводит 1.

Все, все глобальные переменные инициализированы. Переходим к `main()`, и видим, что она ничего не делает.

Программа завершена. Все ее внешнее проявление - вывод 1...

Answer (score 3):

Все логично добавим пару пробелов, что бы было очевидно

```
++x + -+y + -+z++
```

то есть, у нас три слагаемых, а также есть унарные плюсы (которые ни на что не влияют) и унарные минусы, которые меняют знак.

упростим

```
++x - y - z++
```

теперь уже легче. значение x будет увеличено до сложения, там будет 1. y не меняется, там ноль. z будет изменен, но после сложения, поэтому там ноль. 1 - 0 - 0 == 1.

P.S. Некоторые могут решить, что здесь не инициализированные переменные x,y,z, но нет, они инициализируются нулем.

P.S. - на собеседовании, когда я получил подобный вопрос, я сказал: "а в коде такое тоже есть?" и не принял оффер, хотя он и был хороший.

Comment: Ну и зря не приняли оффер. Довольно часто на собеседованиях спрашивают то, что в реальной жизни вообще не понадобится никогда и в реальном коде такого конечно нет. Это просто тесты на сообразительность. )

Comment: я все правильно сделал. Там был ещё один вопрос с UB. Но даже после моего ответа, что там UB, мне все равно предлагали угадать ответ. Если бы после ответа, что там UB успокоились, то возможно было бы по другому.

Comment: На собеседовании такие простые вопросы тоже задаются?...

Comment: а почему бы и нет. Не все сходу помнят, сколько 2 в 8.

Comment: Исходное выражение эквивалетно `++x - y - z++` для случая в вопросе, но не в общем случае для произвольных классов.

Comment: это с++. здесь все может быть. Я могу добавить пару макросов и в этом случае все будет совсем странно, даже без классов.